# Regex to find pattern only within a sentence

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract a pattern with two words/terms but only when they occur inside a sentence, in this test case both "pattern" and "sentence". So:

```
Find the pattern when it is. In the same sentence. Find the pattern when it is in the same sentence.
```

Should only find a match in last sentence.

As you can see in my Regex101 test, `(?P<Capture>pattern.*?sentence).*?\.` finds it regardless:

https://regex101.com/r/xDIU5q/2

As far as I understand, I have asked regex to non-greedily match until it finds a period. But this doesn't seem to be limiting it to do so.

Comment: `.*?` matches anything (lazily, except newlines), including periods

Comment: Try using `pattern[^.]*`, that should get you on the right track

Answer (score 0):

https://regex101.com/r/V1aGaY/4

Pattern: `((?<=\s)[^.]+(pattern)[^.]+(sentence)(?=\.)|(?<=\s)[^.]+(sentence)[^.]+(pattern)(?=\.))`

Test string: `Find the pattern when it is. In the same sentence. Find the pattern when it is in the same sentence. Find the sentence when it is in the same pattern.`

This should get you what you need, I believe. This assumes that sentences are delimited by space -- that can easily be modified, just LMK.

Comment: You look ahead finds the dot but the way you have it, it must immediately follow the word sentence.  Maybe you don't need to lookahead at all `[^\.]+(pattern)[^\.]+(sentence)[^\.]+\.`

Comment: You're right in the sense that the lookahead isn't necessarily needed. I admit fully that they might want to keep the period or full-stop. If that's the case, I'll amend my post. I just didn't really think it was a big deal...

Comment: I wasn't complaining about whether the dot was kept or not.  I was just saying that the regex requires the word "sentence" to be the last word in the sentence.

Comment: Ah, I see your point. I can update my answer.

Comment: Why escaped [^\.] and class [\s] - they add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Fixed, I think. Thanks.